# jQuery Simple Vertical Accordion Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

how can i do when i click 'Item' it will open and when click again it will close 
in Vertical Accordion Menu:

```
<style>
    #nav { float: left; width: 280px; border-top: 1px solid #999; border-right: 1px solid #999; border-left: 1px solid #999; } #nav li a { display: block; padding: 10px 15px; background: #ccc; border-top: 1px solid #eee; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; text-decoration: none; color: #000; } #nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active { background: #999; color: #fff; } #nav li ul { display: none; // used to hide sub-menus } #nav li ul li a { padding: 10px 25px; background: #ececec; border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc; }
    </style>  

    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

when i click Item 1,Item 2  it will open sub menus but if i click it again it did not close it.

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m1556tva/) what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `else` in your jquery to catch the click if the item is already `active`

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#nav li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't work because it didn't run any code on links that already had the `active` class.

You can achieve what you want with less code.

```
$('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    $('#nav > li > a').not(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kapoko/c6jmb796/)